# Automatically expand WinForms panel vertically to bottom of container

Tags: winforms

I am trying to establish the following behavior: When hiding the bottom (blue) panel I want the top (red) panel to stretch to replace it vertically and vice versa (hiding red panel should expand blue).

Using a table layout panel with auto sized rows I was able to get the blue to stretch upwards but I can not get the red panel to grow downwards.

[image]

It's difficult to see from the far right picture but the bottom table row did not shrink with the panel. Table layout panel is not a requirement for me but I was hoping it would offer a solution.

Comment: TLP will certainly do this.  Just delete the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a SplitContainer control instead.

You can control each panel's visibility with the Collapsed properties:

```
splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = true;
```

or

```
splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
```